# How to call a function with a parameter in another function in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have function which returns some value. In the function parameter I pass the same value:

```
 fun getValue (value:String):String {
        var message = value
        value = "Hello"
        return message
    }
```

How can I call `getValue` function in another function? For example:

```
fun getResult (){
var a = getValue (what here?)
}
```

Comment: For example with a string literal: `var a = getValue ("Hello")`. Also note that the assignment `value = "Hello"` inside the `getValue` function is useless. What did you intend to achieve?

Comment: But when I call `getValue` method I need in resalt `var a = message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function as a prameter for another function in kotlin.
Kotlin functions can take other functions in arguments, or even return them.

```
fun getResult (func:(String) -> String) {
        //some code
        var a = func("some string")
    }

    fun getValue (value:String):String {
        var message = value
        return message
    }
```

and call getResult and pass function to it:

```
getResult({  getValue("Hello") })
```

Comment: in this case here `getResult(getValue("Hello"))` I get error: `Type mismatch.
Required:
(String) → String
Found:
String`

Comment: @Julia Sorry , I edit and test my answer. Please try again.

Comment: but for example I get in `message' (`getValue` method) "DDD" value. How can I do that here `var a = func("some string")` I get "DDD"too?

Comment: @Julia I hope underastand your mean. If you mean return back result from getResult() function, e.g. a value, do like other function. It's enough to change type of return back in getResult() function. easily change to:  fun getResult (func:(String) -> String):String { //TODO return a}. If my answer can help you and is correct, please accept it. Thanks tou if upvote useful comments too. Good Luck.